# conditional set parameter in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have this table:

### Contract

### | id | personId | initDate | endDate |

I would like to include in hibernate query the personId just when personId > 0 and/or a between with the dates when they are different from null.

I have:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Contract")
```

How can I set the parameters correctly after check the conditions?

```
public List<Contract> getByPersonIdAndDates(int personId, Date initDate, Date endDate) {
        if(personId > 0)
...
        if(initDate != null and endDate != null)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Criteria. It is just a template (don't know how you working with dates)

```
public List<Contract> getByPersonIdAndDates(int personId, Date initDate, Date endDate) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Contract.class);
    if (personId > 0) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("person.id", personId);
    }

    if (initDate != null && endDate != null) {
       criteria.add(Restrictions.between("date", initDate, endDate);
    }

    return (List<Contract>)criteria.list();
}
```